# Inner products: when a bound on a matrix-vector product implies a bound on the vector norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times c}$ and a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^c$.

I know that

$$
||Mv||_2 = 1
$$

and that $||M|| = 1$. When can I say that the norm of $v$ is bounded in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|Mv\| = 1$ means $Mv$ is a unit vector. Let $u = Mv$, then

$$Mv = u,$$

which means $v$ can be any vector in affine space $u + V$, where $V$ is the null space of $M$, or equivalently $V = \{x: Mx = 0\}$. Therefore, $v$ is not bounded if the rank of $M$ is smaller than the dimension of $v$, i.e., $M$ does not have full column rank.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=diag(1,0)$ and $v_n=(1, n)^T$, then $\|v_n\|\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\to\infty$